# Change classname but doesn't reflect the result

Tags: javascript, dom

I use twitter bootstrap to write the following to form validation and if error should change the helptext and change the class name, but it seem doesn't change the result.(background should be red).

The alert result is `alert alert-error`.

how should I fix it? Thx in advance.

html

```
<label>Account</label>
<input id="stdAccount" name="account" type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge" onblur="validateAccountAndID(this,document.getElementById('stdAccountHelp'));">     
<div class="" id="stdAccountHelp"></div>
```

js

```
function validateAccountAndID (inputField, helpText) {
    if(!validateNonEmpty(inputField, helpText))return false;
    else {
        var regex = /^\d{1,10}$/;
        if(!regex.test(inputField.value)){
            helpText.classname = 'alert alert-error';
            helpText.innerHTML = "Only allow <= 10 numbers!";
            alert(helpText.classname);
            return false;
        }
    }
        helpText.classname = '';
        helpText.innerHTML = "";
        return true;    
}
```

Comment: Doesn't Bootstrap require jQuery? Why don't you use that for this kind of thing?

Comment: shouldn't that be helpText.className (capital N)?

Comment: I havn't learned jquery, I already learned some javascript so I use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
 helpText.className = 'alert alert-error';
```

`className` is the attribute to get/set the class of a dom element, not `classname`.